# Toolbar not visible in collapsed state inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. When I scroll up the viewpager scrolls as normal but when it is collapsed the toolbar should be visible but it seems it stays behind the viewpager as I can see the snapping of the toolbar when I scroll up. I have gone through several discussions on stackoverflow but didn't find the solution. Please help me to identify what I'm missing here.

[[image: Expanded]][10][[image: Collapsed]][10]

This is my layout xml -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/colorAppBg"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
              android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="300dp"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                 android:id="@+id/toolBarLayout"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
                 app:scrimAnimationDuration="200"
                 app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="@dimen/scrimTrigger">
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/actionBarElevation"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                       android:id="@+id/locationPager"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                       android:id="@+id/locationPagerIndicator"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                       app:fillColor="@color/colorText"
                       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                       app:pageColor="@color/colorText"
                       app:radius="3dp"
                       app:strokeWidth="0dp"/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/titleView"
                       style="@style/TextViewNormal"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="@string/app_name"
                       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <TextView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                 android:padding="10dp"
                 android:text="hh"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                 android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was

```
android:elevation="@dimen/actionBarElevation"
```

in FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/frame"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:elevation="@dimen/actionBarElevation"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
```

It is working as expected after removing this line of code. But I don't know what is the problem with this. However I get warning in editor saying Attribute elevation is only used in API level 21 and higher. I don't think it should create any problem as I'm running the app in device which has the api level 25. and the app's target sdk is 26 and min sdk is 16.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code .It worked ok in my code .

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="@dimen/actionBarElevation"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            <!-- add your code here -->
        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleView"
                style="@style/TextViewNormal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I tried adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in toolbar. Still the toolbar not visible when collapsed.

Comment: You can check again.

Comment: Same result even after adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" to CollapsingToolbarLayout. However the toolbar is now sticking below the status bar but the viewpager is still on the top of it.

Comment: You can check it now .

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. The code posted by you is working when there is no PagerAdapter assigned to ViewPager which is inside the FrameLayout. When I assign the adapter to the viewpager then the toolbar with textview is not visible.

Comment: You can call `ViewPager ` outside of `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Update on this - when I remove `CirclePageIndicator` and keep `ViewPager` only then the toolbar is visible properly on collapse.

Comment: You should use `viewpager` instead of `NestedScrollView` in your code .It will display well .And you also can add `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` .And it will be good .